# @Cacheable is ignored when orm.xml is used in JBoss7 + JPA(Hibernate) + Infinispan

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jpa-2.0, infinispan, cpu-cache

I’m trying to use JPA second level cache on JBoss 7.1. and trying to have:

- Use `@Cacheable` annotation for entity caching.
- Use orm.xml only for named queries.

When second level cache and selective caching is enabled through persistence.xml, it seems `@Cacheable` annotation is ignored and the entities won’t get cached in L2 cache.

I know if I add entity elements with cacheable=”true” in orm.xml, L2 cache works, but is it possible to use `@Cacheable` annotation along with orm.xml?
I want to use JBoss 7.1, JPA (backed by Hibernate), Infinispan as the second level cache provider.

[Persistence.xml]

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true" />
```

Comment: What seems? I don't see, show us!

Comment: I found this problem only happens with JBoss 7.1.3 or greater and the current release version 7.1.1 doesn’t have this problem. I'll just forget about this problem until next version is released.

Comment: Did you report it? If noone does, it's unlikely to get magically fixed for the next version.

Comment: Hi Sanne, I posted a discussion in Jboss Community (https://community.jboss.org/thread/220403)